# Node Axios POST is throwing 500 error on nested data object but works with a flat object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, axios

I am making a very simple `POST` request with `axios` in an `expressjs` app like so:

```
const try = async () => {
  const axios = require('axios');
  const output = { url: "www.example.com"}
 
  await axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/myapp`, output)
  // do something else
}
```

The above requests works. However, when I change `output` to :

```
const output = {
    url:{
        test: "www.example.com"
    }
}
```

The post request throws:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:339:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:548:15)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1289:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
```

Why is there a problem with a **nested** Object but not a flattened one?

Comment: _"Why is there a problem with a nested Object but not a flattened one?"_ - most likely because the remote endpoint you are sending this to, expects a certain data structure ... and not a completely different one?

Comment: Can you show your backend code? My guess is that you need to add content type application/json; a flat object probably translates to keys & (string) values, a nested object therefore throws an error.

Comment: @CBroe you are right. Issue was with the remote endpoint's data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is sending data to a `nosql` management system which is setting certain default data types on first sending the request.

Sending the request again with different data types will cause an error. The  issue was resolved by making sure data sent to the dbms was consistent.

If sending `javascript` objects whether they are stringified or not makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In this request you Send Two url at same time in axios. I think this error because this.

Comment: No, This:  `url: "www.example.com"` is just part of the output data it could have been any other string other than a url.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).